# How do I create an instance of a class with two generic types?

Tags: java, generics, types

I'm trying to create an instance of a class ZipIterator which takes two arbitrary arrays as arguments and sets them equal to two private fields K[] and V[] via the constructor. In my Testing class' main method, I'm writing

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ZipIterator<K,V>
{
    private K[] arr1;
    private V[] arr2;
    private int pos = 0;

    public ZipIterator(K[] arr1, V[] arr2) {
        this.arr1 = arr1;
        this.arr2 = arr2;
    }

}
```

In my Testing class' main method, I'm trying to create a ZipIterator object like this

```
int[] arr1 = {1,5,3,1,6};
double[] arr2 = {2.3,42.1,1.6,6.43};
ZipIterator<int[],double[]> zip =  new ZipIterator<int[],double[]>(arr1,arr2);
```

but I keep getting the error:

```
error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int[][]
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong. If anybody can help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't use primitive types with generics. Use the `Integer` and `Double` wrapper types.

Comment: You've set `K` to `int[]`, and the constructor is expecting a `K[]`, which would be an `int[][]`.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the signature of `ZipIterator<K[], V[]>` when `K` is `int[]` and `V` is `double[]`.

What you need to instantiate is `ZipIterator<Integer, Double>`; you cannot parametrize a class with a primitive type.

Yes, it's inefficient because of boxing/unboxing. If you want higher performance, make wrapper classes that keep an array of a primitive type as an instance variable. Will be tricky to make it nicely parametric, though.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely what happens:

You are using `int[]` as generic type `K`:

```
ZipIterator<int[], double[]> zip = new ZipIterator<int[],double[]>(arr1, arr2);
```

Your constructor, however, is accepting an array of `K`, so an array of `int[]` would require `int[][]`:

```
public ZipIterator(K[] arr1, V[] arr2) { ... }
```

---

**Notes:**

- *You shouldn't use arrays with generics, use the `List` interface instead:*

  ```
  public ZipIterator(List<K> arr1, List<V> arr2) { ... }
  ```

  *Or, like [4castle mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726312/how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-a-class-with-two-generic-types/42726497#comment72572541_42726497), you can even use the `Iterable` interface.*
- *Unlike what others said, an array is always an object, even if it is an array of a primitive type. So using `int[]` for `K` is perfectly valid, whilst `int` is not.*

Comment: In this case they could probably even use `Iterable` instead of `List`

Answer (score -1):

It should be
`ZipIterator<int,double> zip =  new ZipIterator<int,double>(arr1,arr2);`

Comment: This doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Use the wrapper classes

```
Integer[] arr1 = {1,5,3,1,6};
Double[] arr2 = {2.3,42.1,1.6,6.43};
ZipIterator<Integer,Double> zip =  new ZipIterator<>(arr1,arr2);
```

Edited my answer based on the comment by @4castle